# Push specific, non-repeating value from JSON set into .each statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an `each` statement like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, value) {

        sublayers.push({
            sql: "SELECT " + firstSel2 + ", cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2 where " + firstSel2 + "='" + value.attri_1 + "'",
            cartocss: "#full_data_for_testing_deid_2 {marker-fill:"+color_here+";marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.2;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;}"
       });     
    });
```

In the cartocss portion, there's a variable `color_here`. This is what I need to replace. This needs to be a hex value from an object like this:

```
var myColors = ["#364C57",
"#666DD6",
"#867EAD",
"#1A3D76",
"#7F787F",
"#35304C",
"#1D5772",
"#15446B",
"#7382C0",
"#484A48",
"#454252",
"#333C6F"];
```

What I need is for the each statement to pull out one of these colors (starting from the top) for each `value` that it loops through without repeating. Assume that there will never be more loops than there are colors in my object above. Is there a way to do this that ensures the colors don't repeat for a given each statement? I can come up with something that randomly picks from the list, but it would result in the possibility of a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you need just to select the color from the array according to the current index:

```
var color_here = myColors[i];
```

doesn't it? Place it before `sublayers.push()`.

Comment: Worked perfectly and a super simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: @jon you could have accepted it 2 mins ago, I wanted to have 300 reps that day, why you didn't do it :D

Comment: Sorry. I owe you one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this what you want:

```
    var color_curr;
    var myColors = ["#364C57",
    "#666DD6",
    "#867EAD",
    "#1A3D76",
    "#7F787F",
    "#35304C",
    "#1D5772",
    "#15446B",
    "#7382C0",
    "#484A48",
    "#454252",
    "#333C6F"];
    $.each(data, function(i, value) {
    var color = myColors[i];
    if(color!=color_curr){
            sublayers.push({
                sql: "SELECT " + firstSel2 + ", cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2 where " + firstSel2 + "='" + value.attri_1 + "'",
                cartocss: "#full_data_for_testing_deid_2 {marker-fill:"+color_here+";marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.2;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;}"
           });  
    }
    color_curr=color;

});
```